# Work with Gradle from Java/Groovy application

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, gradle

Purpose of my project is to build, test and display test results of some codebase that is under test. For my needs I've create Gradle project. Everything works good with aim of console. 
But now I want to work with this "test-suite" project from my main Java/Groovy project which is web service.

So I want to know is there any way to find Gradle Java/Groovy "client" wrapper? Or does Gradle has features to call tasks externally?

Also I wonder what is the best way to understand that Gradle build is failed? Should I parse build console output or can I setup some error codes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if the goal is to integrate Gradle into some other tool, you should use the Gradle Tooling API.

Comment: Thank you, my bad, I reviewed the documentation w/o necessary attention.